# mod_rewrite to capture subdomain name

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I want to write a rewrite scheme such that:

- `user1.example.net` will redirect to `example.net/user/user1`
- `user2.example.net` will redirect to `example.net/user/user2`

This is what I have in my `.htaccess` code. But it always redirects to `example.net`.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^[^.]+\.example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example\.net(.*) http://example.net/user/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/user/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```